# HTTP Set-cookie Headers not taken into account by browser

Tags: django, http, cookies, http-headers

I have a web server that is serving files. Here is a request I make and the answer:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8004
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20131030 Firefox/17.0 Iceweasel/17.0.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: djdt=hide; sessionid=1ksbrjhfunsjtywlk2q4p2rl7zrsyvza; messages="Nice and all"
Cache-Control: max-age=0


HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=Xkg4CnLEahplJPHEJGLrmGvPjebMqyh9; expires=Mon, 09-Feb-2015 21:15:51 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/, sessionid=qy5guifmpkra78ubkztxxlmk3tu5vr7s; expires=Mon, 24-Feb-2014 21:15:51 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/, messages=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Vary: Cookie
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 21:15:51 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Up to that point everything is fine. Things get weird on the very next request:

```
GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8004
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20131030 Firefox/17.0 Iceweasel/17.0.10
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8004/
Cookie: djdt=hide; sessionid=1ksbrjhfunsjtywlk2q4p2rl7zrsyvza; messages="Nice and all"
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 20:23:36 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0


HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 21:15:54 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Content-Length: 0
```

Yeah, the browser (Iceweasel) just sent the previous cookies, instead of sending the new one. Actually, it does not take the set-cookie HTTP header into account. That I don't understand. Same behavior on Chromium. On both browsers, nothing appears in the console. When using the developers tools from Iceweasel to the see the request, the previous cookie is parsed in the 'sent cookie', but the received cookie isn't parsed as it should be, such as it is in this (otherwise unrelevant) capture: [image: Example of received cookie being parsed]

You may have notice the Server HTTP response header is different when serving the static file. Indeed, the local Django app serves as a proxy when requesting pages, but serves static content himself. Both contents are on the same domain, same port, so this is supposed to be the same from the browser perspective.

Comment: Please, anyone has _any_ thoughts? I went through the RFC for Cookies, and as far as I've seen, no special condition are needed to take the Set-Cookie into account.

Comment: OK, I avoided the problem by specifying another cookie name for the sessionid of my local Django, using SESSION_COOKIE_NAME. Now the browser keep both sessions without the need to overwrite any. This HTTP header problem is probably one of the weirdest that I have encountered.